# Ruby on rails error Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is happening with rails? A couple of days ago I everything was running smoothly and now trying to spin up the server I'm getting this error

```
Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

running bundle install will create a massive cache folder under vendor and I'm able to spin up the server. However, deleting this cache folder everything breaks again. I'm running rails 6.0 and ruby 2.6.1.

Comment: are you executing 'bundle exec rails server' or just `rails server` - your gem ENV seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I had Ruby installed via rbenv, but rails via apt-get.

Installing rails with 'gem install' instead of 'apt' made it work for me.